# deleting 800 million orphan records from a table containing 1.5 billion records in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sql-tuning

My question is about deleting orphan records in oracle. I have table A in oracle 11.2 database which has 1.4 billion total records with 800 million orphan records. I identified the 800 million orphan records in table A. Created the table B with just the id's (primary key) that are orphan records from table A. Now i want to create 8 tables with ids, 100 million of ids from table B in each of the 8 tables. I want create and run a procedure which will delete the 800 million orphan records from table A where the id is in each one of the 8 tables and create 8 procedures to run 4 procedures in parallel session at a time. I mean parallel session not Parallel DML/query option or not parallel hint. I can not use CTAS, create table as select option here. Please respond. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dbms_parallel_execute procedure that does exactly what you intend to do.
I had [blogged about it a while back](http://dba-blogs.blogspot.com/2013/04/delete-huge-amount-of-rows-using.html). Hope it helps.

Comment: or he can just parallel hint it via a simple SQL

Comment: Please copy the relevant information from the blog post to this answer. Without it this is just a link-only answer to an off-site resource. Thanks.